# How to find a tag by specific text in Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Do you know how to search for specific text inside pythons `BeautifulSoup`, to find tags - better full path to tags, containing some `string`?

The common way of `BS4` usage is for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://elementy.ru/novosti_nauki"


website = requests.get(url)
results = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
```

and then you can query for all tags with some properties, like header, class, etc.

However I want to go different way, and find the location of the specific text inside this structure?

If you do it with plain HTML text it is really unconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `css selector` or more exactly the Soup Sieve pseudo class `:-soup-contains()` to search for tags that contains a certain string:

```
soup.select(':-soup-contains("that")')
```

or as alternative `re.compile()`:

```
import re
soup('p', text=re.compile('that')))
```

**Note:** *If you use `soup.find_all(string="that")` this wont work, cause it expects to match the exact string.*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>some content</p>
<p>pattern that we like</p>
<p>some content</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select(':-soup-contains("that")')
```

##### Output

```
[<p>pattern that we like</p>]
```

Comment: wow thanks. I do not need regex since it does not show the place in xml structure, other hint is great

Comment: ok, the issue i found this selects entire document from me starting from html and boy tags, do you know how to change request so the selected element will be as small as possible?

Comment: *as small as possible* - Without improving your question with additional details e.g. expected output it would be guessing: `soup.select('p:-soup-contains("that")')` would focus directly on  `<p>`,...

Comment: so you just put selection before this expression. awsome, thanks